# Batch Insert with Mysql Connector for .NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, bulkinsert

I was wondering if there is any Bulk Insert functionality available on the MySql Connector.
I do have to create millions of records and I believe the batching will be a great feature for this.

I'm working on an MVC project with a MySql datastore.

Thanks,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with .NET, but can you use the [LOAD DATE INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)-option in MySQL? It can do millions of records per minute, depending on your database hardware.

Good luck!

Comment: I was looking for something more programming related. But I will take your advice in case there is too slow.